# Access dialog in callback method with proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently creating a dialog within a user-define class:

```
$("<div>").dialog(buttons: {
   'one': function () {
      $(this).dialog('close').dialog('destroy');
   }
});
```

The above works fine, however, `this` no longer refers to the class instance in the above function.  I can get around this with `$.proxy`:

```
...buttons: {
   'one': $.proxy(function () {
      this.doWork();
   }, this)
```

Then, I can call class methods when the dialog button is clicked.

However, I still need to call `.dialog('close').dialog('destroy')` on the dialog element itself.  After redefining `this` with `$.proxy`, how can I access that element in the button callback?  `e.target` refers to the button itself.

I also realize I can do something like this:

```
var obj = this;
...buttons: {
   obj.doWork();
```

but I'm looking for a way around that.

Comment: if want access to both objects, what would benefit be of using `proxy` to change context

Comment: `$(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').prev()` will give you main element

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uwidah/1/edit `this` points to initial element, whats wrong ?

Comment: @charlietfl how can I access the class instance *without* redefining it in the higher scope?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: The `var obj = this` solution is a common practice. There might not be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: ah i understand problem now, seems I can find a solution... :)

Comment: why can't just use class object within the dialog callback?  `myClass.doWork()`

Comment: @charlietfl because it's an instance method, not a class method

Comment: btw, in case of `$.proxy()` this will show to the element, which invoked action, not to the class instance... http://jsbin.com/uwidah/4/edit, better to use `var that=this` in class header, I personally see no reason to avoid that

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uwidah/11/edit that is sample of `var` it looks **much** better for me than use proxy or any other complex solutions

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I suppose a closure on `one` handler is also against what you want to achieve right?

Comment: @Alexander I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: @ExplosionPills, e.g. `'one': function(self){ return function(){ ... }; }(this)`. A narrower scope

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately `self` in that context would be the event object, and I don't know how to get the dialog element from that.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I can't see it is the Event object. I know it is untested but there's `...(this)`

Comment: @Alexander good spot, unfortunately that [works](http://jsbin.com/uwidah/13/edit) like a [proxy](http://jsbin.com/uwidah/4/edit) , I think that closure should be initialised when you initialise dialog: 
[`this.dialog_open=function(that){return  function () {`](http://jsbin.com/uwidah/14/edit)

Comment: @eicto, what's unfortunate? You have access to both contexts whereas using `$.proxy` you can't. Anyways, I beg to differ but it's not the same behaviour as using `$.proxy` at all

Comment: @Alexander I linked to the samples, if you use closure or proxy when initialising button, you will get other scope than scope of class, check the console in [that example](http://jsbin.com/uwidah/13/edit)

Comment: @eicto: That's because you sent dlg.dialog_open as a direct reference in the click handler, so it will not be executed in the context of the class. You need to wrap it in an anonymous function.

Comment: @wired_in thanks, but it is strange :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid `var obj = this;` inside the class's scope, but the only other way would be with a self-invoking closure which does essentially the same thing. In order to have a reference to both contexts, you need to store the class reference in a different variable.

With closure:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.createDialog = function () {
        $("<div>").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "one": function (self) {
                    return  function (e) {
                        self.doWork();
                        $(this).dialog("close").dialog("destroy");
                    };
                }(this)
            }
        });
    };

    this.doWork = function () {
        // do work
    };
}

$(function () {
    var obj = new MyClass();

    $(".createDialog").click(function () {
        obj.createDialog();
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar4ZL/